# How do I change the width and color of Material UI tab indicator?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I want to change the width and color of the Material UI tab indicator, and the active tab indicator should be different.
[PFA image for the reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qjhZh.png)

I tried adding borderBottom, but it goes down the indicator.

The width of indicator should fit to its parent, and the active tab indicator should be of label size.